# FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() crashing app

Tags: java, android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build a tracker app using Google Maps API and Firebase.
I am trying to use the getValue() method in onStart() to take values from Firebase and use them  as latitude and longitude to display location. My code:

**MapsActivity.java**

```
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private DatabaseReference mRootReference =firebaseDatabase.getReference();
private DatabaseReference mChildReference=mRootReference.child("Raunak Trikha");
private DatabaseReference mChildReference1=mChildReference.child("id");
private DatabaseReference mChildReference2=mChildReference1.child("lat");
private DatabaseReference mChildReference3=mChildReference1.child("long");

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    mChildReference2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            rlat=dataSnapshot.getValue(double.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}`
```

Whenever I try to run this app in my AVD it crashes.

Comment: `"Raunak Trikha"` should not be a key. Keys should not contain spaces.

Comment: But we still need to see the stack trace of your error too to know the real problem.

Comment: "Raunak Trikha" is the first child of root. Anyway the app crashes on this statement:`private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();`

Comment: please post complete stacktrace.

Comment: here is the link: https://imgur.com/nS0wHV2

Answer (score 0):

You have to call

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
```

line, when your app started?

At `onCreate()` method of first activity or application class.

Comment: This could be the actual solution but you stated it like a comment.

Comment: At onCreate() method of your first activity or application class.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify your code, please use the following lines:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference latRef = rootRef.child("Raunak Trikha").child("id").child("lat");
DatabaseReference longRef = rootRef.child("Raunak Trikha").child("id").child("long");
latRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
longRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

All this lines are needed in `onCreate()` method.